# How to plot the periodic signal using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to plot for signal y(t)=sin(t)+2cos(2t) using MATLAB .

I have done  coding for 1 periodic cycle but i want it for 4 periodic cycles.

Also, if i want to give notations on x axis  like T,2T,3T,4T **to denote completed periodic cycles of y(t)** ,then what i have to add in the code

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

t = 0:0.01:2*pi;
y=sin(t)+ 2*cos(2*t);

plot(t,y);grid on
```

Comment: `t = 0:0.01:4*2*pi;` ?

Comment: @LuisMendo thank u sir, now, i want to add notations on x axis like T,2T,3T,4T to denote completed periodic cycles of y(t)

Comment: See this for exact solution http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To include four periods you can just define `t` as

```
t = 0:0.01:4*2*pi;
```

To use the desired labels, add this at the end of your code:

```
set(gca,'xtick',(1:4)*2*pi) %// set ticks
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'T' '2T' '3T' '4T'}) %// set labels
xlim([0 4*2*pi]) %// avoid too large x axis
```

[image]